# How to get a value of a cell knowing it's unique ID, stored aside?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, vba

I have in my Excel spreadsheet a row which contains product names and a parallel row which indicates their prices (each one has a different price). I need to get the name of the most expensive product. I already know that the MAX function can help me find the highest price, but how do I convert the price into the product's name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH`. Let's say that the first column is in column A and the other is in column B:

```
=INDEX(A:A, MATCH(MAX(B:B), B:B, 0))
```

`MAX(B:B)` gives you the highest price in column B, `MATCH()` returns the row number of that value (the first occurrence if there are many maximum) and `INDEX` returns the corresponding product name from column A:A.

EDIT: I messed up sorry :(

If you want to find the product from the *row* instead of the column, you'll use `1:1` and `2:2` instead of `A:A` and `B:B` respectively, that is:

```
=INDEX(1:1, MATCH(MAX(2:2), 2:2, 0))
```

Comment: I could have sworn I read 'column' in the question D: You're right, though again, I explicitly stated 'column' initially as well in the answer... oh well, gotta love Sundays... :(

Comment: @pnuts, I'll fess up again. I assumed the OP was like me, and sometimes gets their cols and rows mixed up :).